MaxRev.Gdal.Core - OSGeo.OGR driver.createdatasource fails with System.NullReferenceException
I try to create a new GeoPackage file and write some point data into it. But my code already fails, when I try to create the new GeoPackage file.
I try to create this file within an unix/C# environment - for this I'm loading the GDAL/OGR dependencies from MaxRev.Gdal.Core.
The code stops with an unhandled exception:
Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The problem occurs after these two lines:
using MaxRev.Gdal.Core;

...

GdalBase.ConfigureAll();

...

OSGeo.OGR.Driver gpkgDriver = OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.GetDriverByName("GPKG");
var ds = gpkgDriver.CreateDataSource("output.gpkg", new string[] { });    // The problem occurs here.

